# Trying to write HTML using a Modulus conditional using Razor Core6

Tags: c#, razor

I'm trying to get some code to work to make rows from a List of Items. I had done it before but for some reason it's not properly adding the closing tags.

```
    <code>
    @if (Model != null)
{
    var start = 0;
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {

        if (start == 0)
        {

            @:<div class="row"><div class="col-lg-4">
            start++;
        }
        else if (Model.Count == start)
        {
            @:</div>

        }
        else if (start % 3 == 1 && start > 1)
        {

            @:</div>
            start++;

        }
        else
        {
            var price = string.Format("{0:0.00}", item.MenuItemPrice);
                <div class="card">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="~/SiteImages/MenuHome.png" style="width:128px" />
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="card-title">
                            @item.MenuItemName
                            <hr />
                        </div>
                        <p class="card-text>">
                            @item.MenuItemDesc - @price
                        </p>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="fpPlatter">View</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @:</div>
            start++;
            
        }

    }
}
</code>
```

It does write the row but it won't close the col-lg-4. It should write a row, a col-lg-4, then add 3 items based on the modulus and close them at the end. I'm probably overlooking some thing as the List is added. Any input appreciated. I can add a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
<code>
    @if (Model != null)
    {
        var currentCard = 0;
        foreach (var item in Model.Products)
        {
            currentCard++;
            if (currentCard % 3 == 1)
            {
                @:<div class="row">
            }
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="card">
                    @*
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="~/SiteImages/MenuHome.png" style="width:128px" />
                    </div>
                    *@
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="card-title">
                            @item.MenuItemName
                            <hr />
                        </div>
                        <p class="card-text>">
                            @item.MenuItemDesc - @string.Format("{0:0.00}", item.MenuItemPrice)
                        </p>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="fpPlatter">View</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            if (currentCard % 3 == 0 || currentCard == Model.Products.Count)
            {
                @:</div>
            }
        }
    }
</code>
```

You will need to change `Model.Products` to your required Model... it was just me playing around.

Comment: Thanks for the post. I got there after I thought about it.  I'll post when I try a few suggestions.

Comment: If you're using col-lg-4, then you don't even need to worry about the multiple row divs.  In fact, you will have a more responsive UI if you don't manually break your cards into rows and instead depend on Bootstrap's grid.  You can add margins to get card spacing rather than using row for that.

Comment: John, as I was looking at it I realized I didn't need the row. That drops the complexity to one loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are not handling all the items with the current logic. For example on the first iteration the opening div is created, but the item is not written. The html you have in the else probably needs to be done unconditionally and the rest of the optional html needs to be handled the body of the foreach loop in relation to the item html so that it lands in the proper place.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with your conditional logic. However, rather than correct it, you could just abandon it and use Bootstrap's grid system to layout your rows for you.

- outside of your foreach loop, open a row div
- inside your loop, output a card *contained inside a div sized using the grid system*

  `<div class="col-md-4"> <div class="card"> ... </div> </div>`
- after exiting your loop, close the row div

This is the method recommended in [Bootstrap's own documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/card/). It is simpler to implement and also requires less work server-side to generate your HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the post. I will check out Bootstrap's method. What I found was that I'm not adding the col-lg-4s correctly.

Comment: As I was thinking about I realized i didn't need the row div. I had to step back for a minute.